# One extra line being read in file handling

Tags: c++, file-handling

I am trying to get the number of lines and words from a text file in c++. But one extra line is being read by compiler.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    ifstream f;
    string name;
    char a;
    int line, words;
    line = 0;
    words = 0;


    f.open("file.txt");

    while (f) {
        f.get(a);


        if (a == '\n')
        {
            line++;
            words++;
        }

        if (a == ' ')
        {
            words++;
        }

    }
    f.close();
    cout << "Number of words in file : " << words << endl;
    cout << "Numbers of lines in the file : " << line << endl;
}
```

OUTPUT:-

```
Number of words in file : 79
Numbers of lines in the file : 3
```

file.txt:-

```
This C++ Program which counts the number of lines in a file. The program creates an input file stream, reads a line on every iteration of a while loop, increments the count variable and the count variable is printed on the screen.
Here is source code of the C++ program which counts the number of lines in a file. The C++ program is successfully compiled and run on a Linux system. The program output is also shown below.
```

I am puzzled why one extra line is being read. Kindly help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not checking if `f.get()` succeeds or fails.  When it does fail, `a` is not updated, and you are not breaking the loop yet, so you end up acting on `a`'s *previous* value again. And then the *next* loop iteration detects the failure and breaks the loop.

Change this:

```cpp
while (f) {
    f.get(a);
    ...
}
```

to this instead:

```cpp
while (f.get(a)) {
    ...
}
```

That being said, you are also not taking into account that the last line in a file may not end with `'\n'`, and if it does not then you are not counting that line.  And also, you are assuming that every line always has at least 1 word in it, as you are incrementing `words` on every `'\n'` even for lines that have no words in them.

I would suggest using `std::getline()` to read and count lines, and `std::istringstream` to read and count the words in each line, eg:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    ifstream f;
    string line, word;
    int lines = 0, words = 0;

    f.open("file.txt");

    while (getline(f, line))
    {
        ++lines;
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        while (iss >> word) {
            ++words;
        }
    }

    f.close();

    cout << "Number of words in file : " << words << endl;
    cout << "Numbers of lines in the file : " << line << endl;
}
```

Comment: So f.get(a) is failing at the last iteration and because it failing, it's value remains the same ?

Comment: @RishabhGupta Yes. Per [`std::basic_istream<CharT,Traits>::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get): "*Reads one character and stores it to `ch` if available. **Otherwise, leaves `ch` unmodified and sets `failbit` and `eofbit`**.*"

Answer (score 1):

It is because you do not check in what state is stream that `f.get(a)` returns.